# How do you get Community User Contact Id in Aura without Apex

Tags: lightning-aura-components, customer-community, user-record

In an existing Aura component, I'm trying to get Contact Id of Community user without Apex. I'm trying to avoid having to create an Apex class just for this purpose.

I tried below,

```
let userObj = $A.get("$SObjectType.CurrentUser");
console.log('userObj: ' ,JSON.stringify(userObj));
component.set("v.contactId", userObj.ContactId);
```

> userObj:
> {"isChatterEnabled":true,"Email":"dev23@testuseremail.net","Id":"00503000000vaTCAAY"}

But this code snippet doesn't seem to give me the User.ContactId.

Is there a workaround to get Community user's Contact Id in Aura, either in markup or JS without Apex?

Thanks!

Comment: No you cant do that. I've tried previously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can in LWC (and I think also in Aura) - just put this component in your Aura and dispatch a custom event containing the ContactId when you get it.

You are essentially using the getRecord api provided by Salesforce (yes, behind the scenes, it probably uses Apex - but you don't need to write anything) - I'm doing this in LWC because you should be doing all (or almost all) your work in LWC.

Here's the class - it imports the user id and then loads the user record based on that it - which of course includes the contact id, if present.

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord, getFieldValue } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import USER_ID from '@salesforce/user/Id';
import USER_CONTACTID from '@salesforce/schema/User.ContactId';
import USER_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/User.Name';

export default class LwcTester extends LightningElement {

  userId = USER_ID;
  @track user = {}
  error = {};

  @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$userId', fields: [USER_CONTACTID,USER_NAME] })
  wiredUser({ error, data }) {
    if (data) {
      this.user = data;
      this.error = undefined;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.user));
      //at this point you can dispatch your event - something like 'contactidloaded'
    } else if (error) {
      this.error = error;
      this.user = undefined;
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
}
```